# Undesired delay for CABasicAnimation sliding UIView up/down

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a UIView that I am trying to slide off the screen. I attempted to do this with the `[UIView animateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion:]` method but the result was a very choppy animation. To fix this I used the following to slide the UIView "gameLayer" downwards:

```
    CABasicAnimation* theAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    theAnim.fromValue = @(kScreenHeight-150);
    theAnim.toValue = @(kScreenHeight);
    theAnim.duration = 0.4;
    theAnim.beginTime = 0;

    [gameLayer.layer addAnimation:slideDown forKey:@"AnimateFrame"];

    gameLayer.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, kScreenHeight);
```

The animation causes the UIView to jump down slightly (4 pixels or so) and then carry on relatively smoothly. Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: The jump is probably because the `fromValue` is not he same as the current value.

Comment: Also, `beginTime` is not a relative value. If you want it to start immediately you should specify `CACurrentMediaTime()` or just leave it out completely.

Comment: I added some logs and all the values are consistent. Could it be the processor having trouble? I'm testing on an iPhone 4. The UIView being moved is translucent and contains many small images and the background, behind the gameLayer UIView, is an taken by the camera.

Comment: If you suspect that it's a performance problem, the. you need to measure and verify that it is. The Core Animation template in Instruments is a good place to start.